# If I condition my grain, is it ok to wait until I grind it?

Tags: all-grain, grinding

I ran out of time grinding last night, even though I had already conditioned my grain: are there any concerns with leaving some slightly moist grains in a  bucket overnight? I've got about 4 ounces of water in approx. 9.5 lbs of grain.

Comment: You may grow some lactobacillus species in that time...

Comment: OH NO! is there any way to mitigate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, if it doesn't smell foul everything will be fine.   I think for the most part, any lactic acid produced will primarily help to keep your mash pH a little lower (possibly buffering any salts you might add, and possibly helping to aid mash efficiency).

If you wind up tasting something off, you'll know what it was that caused it and know that you don't want to do it again.   Relax, Don't Worry, *etc*.

As far as mitigation if it's too much, brew something that tastes good with a touch of sour (citrusy pale ale, farmhouse beer, stout, *etc*.).

Comment: +1 what he said! If you can keep it cool, e.g. store in a basement/cold room, that will help. But I'd be surprised if 4oz of water would make much difference, but I've never tried it, so please post back how it goes.